# Como tratar swipe horizontal, Windows Phone Silverlight?

Tags: c#, xaml

Primeiramente desculpem o post, estou pelo smartphone.
Bom, estou tentando implantar um menu hambúrguer na minha aplicação silverlight, já tentei o drawer layout, mas o Visual Studio teima em não reconhecer ele. Então tento criar um menu do nada, ta dando certo, so falta o swipe e a transição. Mas no post vim perguntar do swipe, como faço para captar quando o usuário desliza o dedo para direita e esquerda, para abrir e fechar o menu, respectivamente? Não tenho a mente ideia de como fazer, seria um Point ? Ou o que?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui usando o WPToolkit:

**1º** Instalar o pacote do WPToolkit

```
Install-Package WPToolkit
```

**2º** Referenciar o toolkit no xaml:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Antes de:

```
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

**3º** Criar um método dentro do objeto que irá receber a ação de swipe, no meu caso é quando o usuário deslizar sobre o  `ContentPanel`:

```
<!-- Logo, Dentro da Grid ContentPanel -->
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener >
    <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta"/>
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

**4º** Tratar manipulação no .cs

```
private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
{
      if(e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal && e.HorizontalChange > 30)
      {
          painel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
      }

      else if(e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal && e.HorizontalChange < -30)
      {
          painel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
      }

}
```

No caso dei uma folga de 30 px para ele executar o código, assim evitando que o usuário ative acidentalmente o painel... Você pode fazer na Vertical também, basta mudar a `Orientation` dentro do `if` e `else if` para `Vertical`.